# Give Lambda Calculus Term for Haskell Function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computability, lambda-calculus

I am working on a larger project translating Haskell to Lambda calculus. I would like to **give a lambda term to specific Haskell functions**. I am not quite sure how to approach two of them. I went ahead and created the property each term should have, just to give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

What would the $\lambda$-terms for these Haskell functions be? If you could give a brief explanation that would be super helpful.

Function 1: $\mathsf{foldr}$: It should have the property

$$\mathsf{foldr} \, f \, u \, [N_1, \dots ,N_k] \to_\beta^* f N_1 (f N_2 (\dots (f N_k u)))$$

Function 2: $\mathsf{map}$: It should have the property

$$\mathsf{map} \, f \, [N_1, \dots,N_k] \to_\beta^* [f N_1,f N_2, \dots,f N_k]$$

Comment: Do you know how to encode a list of terms into a lambda-term?

Comment: Yes, [N1,N2,...,Nk] = λc.λn.c N1 (c N2 (...(c Nk n)...)). It still doesnt help me though... I am really confused about writing lambda terms for the folders.

Answer (score 1):

Given that a list $[N_1, \dots, N_k]$ of $\lambda$-terms is represented by the $\lambda$-term
$$\lambda c. \lambda n. c N_1 (c N_2( \dots(c N_k n) \dots ))$$
it is easy to define the $\lambda$-terms $\mathsf{foldr}$ and $\mathsf{map}$.

1. $\mathsf{foldr} \, f \, u \, [N_1, \dots, N_k] \to_\beta^* f N_1 (f N_2( \dots (f N_k u) \dots ))$.
   Here, the intuition is to bring $\lambda c. \lambda n. c N_1 (c N_2( \dots(c N_k n) \dots ))$ (i.e. the list $[N_1, \dots, N_k]$) in "head position" and apply it to $f$ and then to $u$, so that, when the $\beta$-steps destroy $\lambda c$ and $\lambda n$, $f$ substitutes for $c$, and $u$ substitutes for $n$. Which $\lambda$-term $\mathsf{foldr}$ allows us to do that?

> ! Let $\mathsf{foldr} = \lambda f'. \lambda u'. \lambda l. lf'u'$. Then,
> \begin{align}
> \mathsf{foldr} \, f \, u \, [N_1, \dots, N_k] &= (\lambda f'. \lambda u'. \lambda l. lf'u')  f \, u \, [N_1, \dots, N_k] 
> \\
> &\to_\beta  (\lambda u'. \lambda l. l f u') \, u \, [N_1, \dots, N_k] 
> \\
> &\to_\beta (\lambda l. l f u) [N_1, \dots, N_k]
> \\
> &\to_\beta [N_1, \dots, N_k] \, f \, u
> \\
> &= \big( \lambda c. \lambda n. c N_1 (c N_2( \dots(c N_k n) \dots )) \big) f u
> \\
> &\to_\beta \big( \lambda n. f N_1 (f N_2( \dots(f N_k n) \dots )) \big) u
> \\
> &\to_\beta f N_1 (f N_2( \dots(f N_k u) \dots )) 
>  \end{align}

2. $\mathsf{map} \, f \, [N_1, \dots, N_k] \to_\beta^* [f N_1, \dots, f N_k]$.
   Here the idea is a variant of the previous point: bring $\lambda c. \lambda n. c N_1 (c N_2( \dots(c N_k n) \dots ))$ (i.e. the list $[N_1, \dots, N_k]$) in "head position" and then replace each $N_i$ with $f N_i$, so as to obtain $\lambda c. \lambda n. c (fN_1) (c (fN_2) ( \dots(c (f N_k) n) \dots ))$, i.e. the list $[f N_1, \dots, f N_k]$.
   How can each $N_i$ be replaced by $f N_i$? The $\lambda$-term $\lambda c. \lambda n. c N_1 (c N_2( \dots(c N_k n) \dots ))$ (i.e. the list $[N_1, \dots, N_k]$) should be applied to the $\lambda$-term $\lambda x . c (fx)$, so that, when the $\beta$-step destroys $\lambda c$ in the list, $\lambda x. c (f x)$ substitutes for $c$ and then $(\lambda x. c (f x))N_i \to_\beta c (f N_i)$.
   Summing up, which $\lambda$-term $\mathsf{map}$ allows us to do all that?

> ! Let $\mathsf{map} = \lambda f'. \lambda l. \lambda c. l \, \lambda x. c (f'x)$. Then,
> \begin{align}
>  \mathsf{map} \, f \, [N_1, \dots, N_k] &= \big( \lambda f'. \lambda l. \lambda c. l \, \lambda x. c (f'x) \big) f \, [N_1, \dots, N_k]
>  \\
>  &\to_\beta \big( \lambda l. \lambda c. l \, \lambda x. c (f x) \big) [N_1, \dots, N_k]
> \\
>  &\to_\beta \lambda c. [N_1, \dots, N_k] \lambda x. c (f x)
>  \\
>  &=
>  \lambda c. \big( \lambda c'. \lambda n. c' N_1 (c' N_2( \dots(c' N_k n) \dots )) \big) \lambda x.c (f x)
>  \\
>  &\to_\beta \lambda c.  \lambda n. (\lambda x.c (f x)) N_1 ((\lambda x.c (f x)) N_2( \dots( (\lambda x.c (f x)) N_k n) \dots ))  
>  \\
>  &\to_\beta \lambda c.  \lambda n. c (f N_1) ((\lambda x.c (f x)) N_2( \dots( (\lambda x.c (f x)) N_k n) \dots ))  
>  \\
>  &\to_\beta \lambda c.  \lambda n. c (f N_1) (c (f N_2) ( \dots( (\lambda x.c (f x)) N_k n) \dots ))  
>  \\
>  &\to_\beta^* \lambda c.  \lambda n. c (f N_1) (c (f N_2) ( \dots( c (f N_k) n) \dots ))  
>  \\
>  &= [f N_1, \dots, f N_k]
> \end{align}

Comment: That is indeed very good Answer. Expanding a bit on the topic. Could the two terms and infinite list be typed as well? As in typed lambda calculus ?

Comment: @gaming4mining - Yes and yes. For infinite lists (in the untyped case, but the typed case is analogous) see also this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3964860/288417) and its accepted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3967995/288417). If you are looking for more specific information, it could be worthy to post a new question.

Comment: @gaming4mining - As a general rule in this site, please if you find an interesting question and/or answer, don't hesitate to upvote them: rewarding is the best spur to high quality questions and answers.

Comment: yes you are right. Is there any specific rule or general consensus why they can be typed? Since here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965504/lambda-calculus-beta-reductions?rq=1 it  it sounds like it can't be actually typed. I'm trying to understand what is the logic for expressions to be "Typeable"

Comment: @gaming4mining - Do you know what a fixpoint combinator is? How it can be represented in the $\lambda$-calculus? The usual representation of a fixpoint combinator cannot be typed (at least with simple types), but you can enrich the $\lambda$-calculus with a special constant representing a fixpoint compinator, and this constant can be typed. Your question deserves a separate post for a decent answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've created a question specifically about these cases [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191270/typed-vs-untyped-lambda-calculus-in-methods-for-haskell?noredirect=1#comment8692159_4191270)