# Infinite lists in Lambda calculus....

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computability, lambda-calculus

I have been learning Haskell for a number of months now and am now trying to understand the underpinning $\lambda$-calculus,  but I have run into a bit of a mental block! How would I go about writing a $λ$-term corresponding to an infinite list (for example  $[0, 1, 2, \dots]$)?

Comment: Do you know about the $\lambda$-calculus fixed-point operator?

Comment: Thanks MJD: Only by definition, haven't really applied it...how would i go about that?

Comment: Sorry, I am still not clear.... how would I solve for the given example. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The infinite list $[0, 1, 2, \dots]$ satisfies the following identity in Haskell (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19749350/6009007)):
$$\tag{1}
[0,1,2, \dots] = 0 : \mathtt{map} \, (+1) \, [0,1,2,\dots]
$$
where $(+1)$ is the function computing the successor of an integer, and $:$ is the function that appends an element to the front of a list.
Indeed, $$\mathtt{map} \, (+1) \, [0,1,2,\dots] = [(+1) \, 0, (+1) \, 1, (+1) \, 2, \dots] = [1, 2, 3, \dots]$$ and clearly
$$0 : [1, 2, 3, \dots] = [0,1, 2, \dots]$$
therefore, Identity $(1)$ holds.

Can Identity $(1)$ be expressed in the $\lambda$-calculus? Yes!
Indeed:

- The natural number $0$ is represented in the $\lambda$-calculus by the Church numeral $\underline{0} = \lambda f. \lambda x. x$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding));
- The function $(+1)$ is represented in the $\lambda$-calculus by the $\lambda$-term $\mathsf{succ} = \lambda n. \lambda f. \lambda x. f(n f x)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Calculation_with_Church_numerals));
- The function $:$ is represented in the $\lambda$-calculus by the $\lambda$-term $\mathsf{cons} = \lambda x. \lambda l. \lambda c. \lambda n. c x (l c n)$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3965504/288417));
- The function $\mathtt{map}$ is represented in the $\lambda$-calculus by the $\lambda$-term $\mathsf{map} = \lambda f. \lambda l. \lambda c. l \, \lambda x. c (f x)$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3961286/288417), unfortunately the author of the question has inexplicably deleted it, I hope he/she will undelete it).

Apparently, the only missing $\lambda$-term to represent $(1)$ in the $\lambda$-calculus is $[0,1,2,\dots]$, that is, the $\lambda$-term that we want to define! Let us denote it by $X$, as an unknown variable in a mathematical equation. Thus, $(1)$ can be rewritten as an equation in the $\lambda$-calculus
$$\tag{2}
X =_\beta \mathsf{cons} \, \underline{0} \, (\mathsf{map} \, \mathsf{succ} \, X)$$
where $=_\beta$ is *$\beta$-equivalence*, that is (roughly), the unoriented version of $\beta$-reduction.
If we can solve Equation $(2)$ (i.e. we find a $\lambda$-term $X$ such that $(2)$ holds), then such a $\lambda$-term represents the infinite list $[0,1,2,\dots]$.
Since $(\lambda x.N)x \to_\beta N$ for any $\lambda$-term $N$, Equation $(2)$ can be equivalently rewritten as
$$\tag{3}
X =_\beta (\lambda x. \mathsf{cons} \, \underline{0} \, (\mathsf{map} \, \mathsf{succ} \, x)) X
$$
Equation $(3)$ is of interest because it says that the $\lambda$-term $X$ we are looking for is a *fixed point* of the $\lambda$-term $\lambda x. \mathsf{cons} \, \underline{0} \, (\mathsf{map} \, \mathsf{succ} \, x)$.
This is where the *[fixpoint combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator)* $Y$ of the $\lambda$-calculus becomes relevant, as correctly suggested by @MJD in his comment.
Indeed, $Y = \lambda f. (\lambda x. f(xx))(\lambda x. f(xx))$ is a "magic" $\lambda$-term such that, for *every* $\lambda$-term $M$,
$$\tag{4}
YM =_\beta  M(YM)$$
that is, $YM$ is a fixed point of *any* $\lambda$-term $M$.
Who cares? From Identity $(4)$, replace the generic $M$ with the $\lambda$-term $\lambda x. \mathsf{cons} \, \underline{0} \, (\mathsf{map} \, \mathsf{succ} \, x)$, so the following identity holds:
$$
Y(\lambda x. \mathsf{cons} \, \underline{0} \, (\mathsf{map} \, \mathsf{succ} \, x)) =_\beta (\lambda x. \mathsf{cons} \, \underline{0} \, (\mathsf{map} \, \mathsf{succ} \, x)) \big( Y (\lambda x. \mathsf{cons} \, \underline{0} \, (\mathsf{map} \, \mathsf{succ} \, x))\big)
$$
This shows that $X = Y (\lambda x. \mathsf{cons} \, \underline{0} \, (\mathsf{map} \, \mathsf{succ} \, x))$ is a solution of Equation $(3)$: just rewrite $(3)$ by replacing $X$ with $Y (\lambda x. \mathsf{cons} \, \underline{0} \, (\mathsf{map} \, \mathsf{succ} \, x))$.
And a solution of Equation $(3)$, and hence of Equation $(2)$, is what we are looking for!

Summing up, the infinite list $[0,1,2,\dots]$ is represented in the $\lambda$-calculus by the $\lambda$-term:
$$
Y (\lambda x. \mathsf{cons} \, \underline{0} \, (\mathsf{map} \, \mathsf{succ} \, x))$$

---

*Digression*. There are different ways to define the $\lambda$-terms $\mathsf{cons}$ and $\mathsf{map}$, depending on the way lists are encoded in the $\lambda$-calculus.

According to the encoding of lists presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3965504/288417), a list $[N_1, \dots, N_k]$ is represented by the $\lambda$-term $$\lambda c. \lambda n.c N_1 (c N_2 (\dots(c N_k n)\dots))$$
and the definitions of $\mathsf{cons}$ and $\mathsf{map}$ above work for this encoding.

An alternative encoding of lists is presented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Pairs), it requires other (just slightly different) definitions of $\mathsf{cons}$ and $\mathsf{map}$.
Note that $Y (\lambda x. \mathsf{cons} \, \underline{0} \, (\mathsf{map} \, \mathsf{succ} \, x))$ always represents the infinite list $[0, 1, 2,\dots]$, provided that $\mathsf{cons}$ and $\mathsf{map}$ are suitable for the encoding of lists under consideration.

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to write up something similar, but it never came out clear enough and not as clear as what you wrote.  Thanks for taking care of it.

Comment: @MJD - Thank you very much! By the way, I like your [blog](https://blog.plover.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your kind words!

Comment: I appreciate both of your efforts. Thank you.