# Lambda Calculus Beta reductions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computability, lambda-calculus

I have two questions about $\beta$-reduction in the [$\lambda$-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). Please find them below. I have also included some background information about how lists (i.e. finite sequences) can be encoded in the $\lambda$-calculus.

**Background information**

Lists can be encoded in the $\lambda$-calculus in the following way: $$[N_1,N_2,...,N_k] ≜ λc.λn.c N_1 (c N_2 (...(c N_k n)...))$$

Intuitively, the variable $c$ represents the cons operation (which adds an item to the head of the list) and the variable $n$ represents the empty list, nil: note that the term for the empty list is $[\,] = λc.λn.n.$, according to the definition above.

**Questions**

Q1.
Show that the following term $β$-reduces to $6$: $[3,2,1] \, \mathsf{times} \, 1$.

Here the natural numbers $1 , 2 , 3 , \dots$ denote the corresponding [*Church numerals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding), that is, the $\lambda$-terms encoding the corresponding natural numbers in the $\lambda$-calculus, and $\mathsf{times}$ is the $\lambda$-term for multiplication. You may use the fact that the $\lambda$-term $\mathsf{times} \, n \, m$ (i.e. $\mathsf{times}$ applied to the Church numerals $n$ and $m$) $\beta$-reduces to the numeral $n×m$.

Q2.
The term $\mathsf{cons}$ appends an element to the front of a list.

$$\mathsf{cons} ≜ \lambda x. \lambda l. \lambda c. \lambda n. c x (l c n)$$

Show that it works by reducing $\mathsf{cons} \, 3 \, [2, 1]$ to $[3, 2, 1]$. Make sure to include every $\beta$-step, and try to use abbreviations for readability.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Ive solved Q1 now, I just had to apply the rule that times n m reduces to nXm, which solves it. However, I am still stuck on Q2. If you could help me get started here, that would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Question 1*. Just apply the definition of list and the fact that $\mathsf{times} \, \underline{n} \, \underline{m} \to_\beta^* \underline{n \times m}$, where $\underline{n}$ is the Church numeral of $n$, for every natural number $n$.

\begin{align}
 [\,\underline{3}, \underline{2}, \underline{1}\,] \, \mathsf{times} \, \underline{1} &= \big( \lambda c. \lambda n. c\,\underline{3} ( c \, \underline{2} (c \, \underline{1} \, n) )  \big) \mathsf{times} \, \underline{1}
\\
 &\to_\beta \big( \lambda n. \mathsf{times} \,\underline{3} ( \mathsf{times} \, \underline{2} (\mathsf{times} \, \underline{1} \, n) )  \big) \underline{1}
\\
 &\to_\beta \mathsf{times} \,\underline{3} ( \mathsf{times} \, \underline{2} (\mathsf{times} \, \underline{1} \, \underline{1}) )  
\\
 &\to_\beta^* \mathsf{times} \,\underline{3} ( \mathsf{times} \, \underline{2} (\underline{1 \times 1}) ) 
\\ 
&= \mathsf{times} \,\underline{3} ( \mathsf{times} \, \underline{2} \, \underline{1} ) 
\\ 
&\to_\beta^* \mathsf{times} \,\underline{3} ( \underline{2 \times 1} ) 
\\
&= \mathsf{times} \,\underline{3} \, \underline{2} 
\\
&\to_\beta^* \underline{3 \times 2} 
\\
&= \underline{6}
\end{align}

*Question 2*. Just apply the definitions of $\mathsf{cons}$ and of list.
\begin{align}
 \mathsf{cons} \, 3 \, [2, 1] &= (\lambda x. \lambda l. \lambda c. \lambda n. cx (lcn)) \, 3 \, [2,1]
\\
 &\to_\beta (\lambda l. \lambda c. \lambda n. c\,3 (lcn))   [2,1]
\\
 &\to_\beta \lambda c. \lambda n. c\,3 ([2,1] cn)
\\
&= \lambda c. \lambda n. c\,3 \big((\lambda c'. \lambda n'. c' 2 (c'  1 \, n')) c\,n \big) 
\\
 &\to_\beta \lambda c. \lambda n. c\,3 \big((\lambda n'. c \, 2 (c \, 1 \, n')) n \big) 
\\
 &\to_\beta \lambda c. \lambda n. c\,3 ( c \, 2 (c \, 1 \, n) ) 
\\
&= [3,2,1]
\end{align}

Note that in Question 2, the fact that $1, 2, 3$ are Church numerals do not play any role.
Actually, $1, 2, 3$ here could be replaced by any $\lambda$-terms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its interesting how the Church numerals dont play a role. Based on this,  I was wondering, how you could write  a λ -term that corresponds to the infinite list [0,1,2,...] ?

Comment: In solution 1: Please, what is the difference between →β and →∗β? (Sorry about the formatting of the reduction arrows)

Comment: @MrNemo - $\to_\beta$ is just one $\beta$-step, obtained by firing exactly one $\beta$-redex $(\lambda x.M)N$; while $\to_\beta^*$ is an arbrtrary number of consecutive $\beta$-steps. In general, reduction of $\mathsf{times} \, \underline{n} \, \underline{m}$ to $\underline{n \times m}$ requires several $\beta$-steps.

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification

Comment: Hi @Taroccoesbrocco I was wondering if the solution for your answer on Mr Nemos question (Infinite List) could also be typed? I dont have enough points to comment on that post unfortunately

Comment: @vatoslocos - The short answer is not. But it depends on the types system you refer to, there are many types systems. I guess you refer to [simple types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus), which cannot type the fixpoint combinator.